# Improving fuel economy in high-milage automatic transmission car

Tags: automatic-transmission, fuel-consumption

Obviously this question is similar to [How to improve fuel economy in high-mileage car?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/2997/how-to-improve-fuel-economy-in-high-mileage-car) except I am asking specifically about automatic transmission car.

The car still delivers lots of power/acceleration but the fuel consumption is very high. **Maybe this is a naive question** but could I somehow set up the automatic transmission software to trade power for fuel efficiency?

**EDIT:**

My car is 2004 Ford Mondeo XL 2.0 Petrol and fuel consumption is cca 15 liter per 100 km (15.7  MPG) in a city.

Comment: This question is a bit vague as written: you've left yourself open to the standard answer of "it's the driver, not the vehicle."  Here are some suggested additions: What specific vehicle are you talking about? What are some of the symptoms that indicate that there is a mechanical problem? Are you already driving in a fuel conserving manner?

Comment: That fuel mileage is shockingly bad. My 4.6L V8 gets like 9-11 l/100km (~23Mpg) I don't have any experience with high milegage motors but that seams really bad for a 2.0l.

Answer (score 1):

Yes depending on the vehicle you can get either chip or OBD port tuners. You can get a tuner to change the automatic shift points of your vehicle to be lower rpms.

You still have to drive nice though!

Answer (score 0):

Simple steps will reduce m.p.g.-correct tyre pressure-don't accelerate rapidly-driving
with windows down or operating air con increase m.p.g. as do weight carried and add-ons
like roof racks.Try and maintain a constant speed. Your transmission can be modified but is not a cheap endeavour