# Reason for high petrol useage (Ford Focus Titanium 2013)

Tags: ford, clutch, focus

I'll start off with the car specs:

2013 Ford Focus Titanium Navigator 1.6L with about 39k miles on the clock.

I recently checked the oil on the engine and it was on the bottom notch of the dipstick. Therefore I topped it up to pretty much above the middle of the 2 notches.

Since then I've noticed that it's consuming alot more petrol than it usually does - I'm sure I'll get shot down for this but I'm been gauging it off the "miles to pump" (M2P) reading.

Driving to work is 4 miles, usually I'll see the M2P reading go down 5-10 miles for the journey (I understand this goes off of driving style) I put half a tank in on Sunday evening (2 days ago) and it's gone down 70 miles since then. Also usually when I turn the engine on the M2P reading goes up about 10 miles. Now I find it goes down?

2nd issue, I find that in 2nd gear up hill - the car jolts, but it's find in all other gears. Could this be the clutch?

What could possibly be the issue? I appreciate its due a service

Comment: Is the check engine light on?  And out of curiosity, the car as a M2P reading, but it _doesn't_ have a average/instant MPG (liters per kilo or whatever) reading?  Rather that focusing on the fuel apparently  used in one trip, "Miles Per Tank" computed manually when you fill up will be the best measurement to use.

Comment: @Jphi1618 No, the engine light isn't on. It does have an average MPG and a live MPG reading though.

Comment: Well, the check engine light rules out a lot of causes.  My M2P meter can get pretty wacky at times, so I would focus on the average MPG.  Also look over [this question](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/2997/12030) for general tips on improving fuel economy.  Your car isn't "high mileage", but most of it applies - check tires, transmission, air filter, etc.

Comment: Nice one @jphi1618, thank you.

I've just booked it in for a full service in 3 weeks, so fingers cross they'll find anything wrong.

Comment: What are your actual drive time(s)?  Only going short distances and times will require more frequent services.  This will be a good read http://www.aa1car.com/library/pm.htmhttp://www.aa1car.com/library/pm.htm  Also, is your car an manual, auto, or manumatic?

Comment: @tobinS Normally around 15-30mins depending on traffic. Can't say I've ever been over 40mph on the way to work either.  It's a manual

Comment: Ask them when you take it in for the service.   Also you will get less MPG when it is colder.   Your injectors may also need cleaning due to lots of short trips.   There are cleaners you put in your petrol tank.